# Magento 2 - setup primary key field without auto increment

Tags: magento2, database, table

I want to set a field in my table database with integer type but with no auto-increment id, is this the right way to do it?

```
$table_lime_provinces->addColumn(
    'provinces_id',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
    null,
    array('identity' => true,'nullable' => false,'primary' => true,'unsigned' => true),
    'Entity ID'
);
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to write this code in your Resource model class

```
$this->_isPkAutoIncrement = false;
```

for example

```
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

class Module extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('table_name', 'table_pk_id');
        $this->_isPkAutoIncrement = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rakesh whai if i turn the `'identity' => false` in add column, is it gonna disable the auto_increment too?

Comment: @IdhamChoudry any update on your question ? 'identity' => false in add column disables the auto_increment or not ?

Answer (score 2):

You can just start using,

**Using identify to false, prevent auto increment for your table.**

```
$table_lime_provinces->addColumn(
            'provinces_id',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
            null,
            array('identity' => false,'nullable' => false,'primary' => true,'unsigned' => true),
            'Entity ID'
        );
```

Comment: Have you try with above code.

Answer (score 0):

First set

> $this->_isPkAutoIncrement = false;

Eg

```
namespace Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

class Module extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('table_name', 'table_pk_id');
        $this->_isPkAutoIncrement = false;
    }
}
```

Then in your setup script

```
->addColumn(
     'table_pk_id',
     \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
     32,
     ['nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
     'Status'
)
```

Since `identity` is default `false` lib/internal/Magento/Framework/DB/Ddl/Table.php

```
$identity = false;
....
if (!empty($options['identity']) || !empty($options['auto_increment'])) {
    $identity = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to figure out why this happens. It's either something I'm just missing, but I've stepped through it 100 times, I've setup the InstallSchema sequence to set 'identity to false, I've deleted all generated code and nothing but setting this class variable to false works. I've got to think this is a huge bug in the Magento code, but I always hate to blame anything but myself for silly, blatant crap like this. So...
Hack in place. Moving on.